# Android App: Pass Javascript Var to Native Java variable

Tags: javascript, java, android

I am creating an Android App and I have the following javascript which is within "str8red.com" loaded from a webview:

```
<script>var name = "bob", age = 30;</script>
```

I have a textbox that I can set using:

```
textView.setText("Static Text")
```

I would like to set my textbox to the variable from the javascript var `name`.  I have tried to utilise `webview.loadUrl("javascript:Android.getIds(Ids);");` and `evaluateJavascript` with no success.  I have also tried to follow numerous guides on stack overflow and the the web without success.

Below is the code for loading the webview:

```
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
//Enable JavaScript
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.setFocusable(true);
wv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
//Set Render Priority To High
wv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
wv.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
//Load Url
wv.loadUrl("https://str8red.com/");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

So, it turns out that for anything from KitKat upwards it is as simple as:

```
    wv.evaluateJavascript("fromAndroid()", new ValueCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
            textView.setText(value);
```

My gap in understanding was I was trying to access the javascript variables directly but this is not what evaluateJavascript is doing.  It seems that it actually runs the chosen javascript function, `fromAndroid()` in this example, and whatever is returned is stored on the native app as a variable.

Below is my javascript code incase it helps:

```
<script>
function fromAndroid(){
  return "{% if user.is_authenticated %}true{% else %}false{% endif %} 1 0";
}
</script>
```

Happy to be created by an expert but I hope this may help someone in the future.